# CosmosDB - Delete item after certain time with condifiton

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to delete a certain item from the DB with a condition:

Delete this item after 72 hours of its creation if c.email_verified is false

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this via the Node SDK, you need to set the TTL at the Item creation by adding a condition, sample code would be

```
const itemDefinition = {
  id: "doc",
  name: "sample Item",
  email_verified: false 
}; 

if(!itemDefinition.email_verified){
       itemDefinition.ttl = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3; //72 hours
}
```

and then create the item. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/fd8a46efb384c8158ef03fff05043af153a8c928/src/test/functional/ttl.spec.ts#L37)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP wants to create the document with a condition that if the email is not verified within 72 hours, then document should be automatically deleted. The document needs to remove the ttl in case the email is verified in 72 hours. In your example, the document will be always deleted after 72 hours.

Comment: oh thanks for pointing it out ! not sure if that's the expectation. tha's also achievable with some logic , when the email is verified, there needs to be an update item with the ttl value -1

Comment: I Was thinking on using a service bus that send a message after some time, this message is consumed and checks that field's value, and delete the user depending the value